# Excel - count number of open items based on two dates

Tags: excel

I have a task I need help with. In my table, I have got two columns with dates:

```
Open        Close
01-Jan-18   02-Jan-18
02-Jan-18   02-Jan-18
04-Jan-18   17-Jan-18
06-Jan-18   10-Jan-18
```

and I want to calculate how many open items I had per each date. So for the 01-Jan-2018 the result is 1 as per line 1. For 02-Jan-2018 result is 2, line 1 (it was closed on the 02-Jan-2018 hence had to be open as well) and line 2. I hope it take sense?

The desired results are here

```
Open        Count
01-Jan-18   1
02-Jan-18   2
03-Jan-18   0
04-Jan-18   1
05-Jan-18   1
06-Jan-18   2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `COUNTIFS()` with some logic:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$5,"<="&A13,$B$2:$B$5,">="&A13)
```

[image]